# In app purchase through distribution profile

Tags: iphone, ios, in-app-purchase

I am trying to implement the in-app purchase but while reading the tutorial-> http://troybrant.net/blog/2010/01/in-app-purchases-a-full-walkthrough/ i come to know that there should be developer provisioning profile instead of distribution profile to test the in-app purchase. I want to hand over the app to my client for testing purpose later on . So my question is should i implement in-app with distribution profile? Will my client able to test it? If Not than any other idea? I havn't said to my client to create developer account till yet. Please help me

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You have to use developer profile for testing in-app purchase, your client will be able to test it(based on type of in-app).